# I am getting a issue in copying a pointer to another pointer in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, copy, c++14

I am getting segmentation fault in first code but the second code is running fine, don't know how?

How can I copy a pointer and save it to another pointer?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int *p;
    int *p1;
    *p1=7;
    p=p1;
    cout<<*p<<" "<<p;
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int *p1;
    *p1=7;
    int *p=p1;
    cout<<*p<<" "<<p;
    return 0;
}    
//7 0x7ffeea73db70
```

Comment: As the old saying goes, "undefined behaviour is undefined". That one of them runs is just bad luck.

Comment: How you allocate memory for your pointers `p` and `p1`?!

Comment: Related: [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior?noredirect=1&lq=1) It's not strictly about pointers, but UB is just the same.

Comment: It would be Undefined Behavior even if you didn't try to assign `7` to `*p1`. You can't even copy an uninitialized pointer, let alone dereference it.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: That's C, not C++. The rationale is similar, but the formal rules are different.

Comment: I recommend you enable your compiler warnings.  That will help guide you from making these kinds of mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both cases invoke undefined behaviour, in both cases you make use of uninitialized pointer `p1`, the fact that the second case "works" for you is a matter of sheer luck, as you can see [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j8RR0bBGoktp9DzX).

For your code to be valid you need to make it point to a valid memory address either by allocating memory manually:

```
int *p1 = new int; //raw pointer, (better to use smart pointers* but let's not get ahead of ourselves).
```

Or by assigning it the address of a valid `int` variable:

```
int i = 5;
int *p1 = &i;
```

> How can I copy a pointer and save it to another pointer?

A pointer is essentially a variable like any other, you can copy it like you do a normal primitive variable, in fact you do just that when you do `p = p1`, these are two different pointers that will now contain the same value, the address of the variable they point to.

[This code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nsyE9XmZQNYw6NH9) exemplifies this

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {

    int *p1 = new int;
    *p1 = 7;
    int *p = p1;
    cout<< "Value stored in the address p points to: " << *p << endl  
        << "Value stored in the address p1 points to: " << *p1 << endl
        << "Address where p points to: " << p 
        << " " << endl <<  "Address where p1 points to: "<< p1 
        << endl << "Address of p: " << &p << endl << "Address of p1: "<< &p1;

    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Value stored in the address p points to: 7
Value stored in the address p1 points to: 7
Address where p points to: 0x804150 
Address where p1 points to: 0x804150
Address of p: 0x7ffc9447e220
Address of p1: 0x7ffc9447e228
```

*[What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: Do you know how to copy a pointer and save it to another pointer?

Comment: @SamareshMaity I edited my answer to address your new question.

Comment: @SamareshMaity, glad I could help, don't forget to [accept one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if any correctly addresses your question.

Answer (score 2):

When you dereference an `int*` pointer, you promise that there is an `int` object at that address. C++ believes you, often without questioning. But you never wrote `int a; p1=&a;` or any other code that made sure `p1` points to an actual `int`.

In fact, `p1` isn't even a null pointer. The only thing you can do with `p1` is to assign it a legal value. That is to say, it must appear at the left-hand side of an assignment first. It can't be used on the right hand side in `int* p = p1;`